# Should I only call my API instead of using socket.emit() on client-side?

Tags: reactjs, database, socket.io, httprequest, chat

I have a chatting application where I'm using socket.io to emit messages between clients, but I also have an API that I call to store the messages the users send in a database.

Since I want the API to be used publicly, it needs to emit socket.io events as well. So, whenever there's a POST request, the message should be emitted to all the clients with socket.io and also be stored in the database. That way though, the client would only do a POST request instead of using socket.emit() on the client-side (only socket.on()).

Is that fine to do, or would it create problems I'm not thinking about?

EDIT:
Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I were to use socket.emit() on the client-side (which I don't want to do), wouldn't anyone be able to edit that out of the code and store messages in the database through the POST request without anything being emitted to anyone's client (considering what I stated above)?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with doing a client side POST/GET request and capture/emit this on the server instead of using client side sockets.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @KurtVandenBranden! Am I correct in saying it's still okay even if the POST requests are quite frequent, like for example as frequent as messages would be in a 10 person group chat where they're all chatting at the same time?

Comment: Yes, it wouldn't make any differences. It's the server that handles all the requests and emits everything to the subscribers.

Answer (score -1):

In this scenario, we have 3 options

1. set your request call every 5 or 10 seconds
2. call messages API on socket events
3. call curl request to hide your API call in the network tab.